# Popup in a Popup - Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox to display youtube video on popups, in popup i used fb share and like button, but when i click the share button it is opening in browser popup, i want to open in fancybox lightbox so it maintains consistency.

Cant figure it out how i display facebook share dialog box in a popup rather than browser popup.

```
$('.fancybox-media')
    .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
    .fancybox({
    href: $(this).attr('href'),
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    autoDimensions: false,
    padding: [15, 15, 0, 15],

    height: 370,
    width: 490,

    arrows: false,
    helpers: {
        media: {},
        buttons: {},
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {

            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http:' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=30" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px; float:right;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http:' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=500&amp;share=true&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=30" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px; float:left;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cant figure it out how i display facebook share dialog box in a popup rather than browser popup.

You can't.

Facebook doesn't allow their login page to be contained inside an `iframe`. This returns an empty window (this is what fancyBox would try to do when clicking the share button)

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/login.php"></iframe>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc5j3/)**